# Array of pointers issue

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i'm having some troubles when passing data from one pointer to an element of an array of pointers of an struct.

```
typedef struct {

    float* data;
    int size;

} vector;

//This function creates the vector

vector* doVector(int n, float* data){

    vector * vec = (vector *) malloc(sizeof(vector));
    vec->size = n;
    vec->data = data;

    return vec;
}

void delVector(vector* v){

    free(v->data);
    free(v);
}

void prVector(vector* v)
{

    printf("[");
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<v->size; i++){
        if(i!=v->size-1)
            printf("%f,", v->data[i]);
        else
            printf("%f]\n", v->data[i]);
    }

}

void fillVectors(float* data,int size){

    vector * vectors = (vector*) malloc(size * sizeof(vector));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        vectors[i] = *doVector(size,data);//This gives trouble
        prVector(&vectors[i]);
    }

    //More stuff will be added here to work with the vectors.

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        delVector(&vectors[i]);//Memory leak here obv

    free(vectors);// I also need to free the array

}

int main()
{

    //Here recieving data from file and calling fillVectors

    //Also allocating memory for data (which is send to fillvectors)

    //Avoided to post because it's irrelevant and big

}
```

So the main idea is to create vectors with the struct,Data and size is read from file and stored into float array called data and int size. Then we call the function fillVector, which will call the doVector function and create the vector itself.

Then I want to assign the value of each vector to a position of the pointer array,(there are 3 mallocs, data and single vector, which is made in doVector, and the array of vectors made in fillVectors).

Problem comes when freeing this pointers, keep getting memory leaks. 
Has something to do with the malloc of the array of vectors and the vector malloc from doVector.

ps: fillVector function is only called once

thanks.

Comment: I can't spot any function named `create_vector()`?

Comment: Changed it's name when posting, sorry. (EDITED)

Comment: C protip: always check if return value of `malloc()` is NULL and/or if the pointer is non-NULL before passing it to `free()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule: in C if want to process smth in function send pointer. So if want to delete vector by pointer then pass pointer to pointer

```
void delVector(vector** v){
    free((*v)->data);
    free(*v);
    *v = NULL;
}
```

Function already returns pointer so no need to use asterisk sign.

```
vectors[i] = *doVector(size,data);
```

Second: you want array of vectors? so use array of pointers to vectors

```
vector **vectors = (vector**) malloc(size * sizeof(vector*));
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    vectors[i] = doVector(size, data);//This gives trouble
    prVector(vectors[i]);//no need to use ampersand, it is already pointer
}
```

And main: you need deep copy of float data inside vector. Now all vectors keep pointer to same array, given as argument. And beside that, you delete this data

```
free(v->data);
```

But this pointer was copied, but not owned.

```
vector* doVector(size_t n, float* data){
    size_t i;
    vector * vec = (vector *) malloc(sizeof(vector));
    vec->size = n;

    vec->data = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vec->data[i] = data[i];
    }
    //or just
    //memcpy(vec->data, data, n*sizeof(float));

    return vec;
}
```

More questions...

Comment: Ty mate. Great answer. Solved lot of doubts

Answer (score 0):

You should be initializing all pointers created and not IMMEDIATELY allocated to NULL or 0 or (void*)0. Then a call to free will clean up any allocated data.

Whenever allocating the actual data type make sure that you set the internal ptr to NULL before you allocate it as well.

### C

```
vector* newVector;
newVector = (void*)0; //or 0, NULL
... //Code here
newVector = malloc(sizeof(vector));
newVector->data = (void*)0;
... //More code

if(!newVector){
    free(newVector);
    newVector = (void*)0;
}
```

### Notes

If you must do dynamic memory allocation, do it in a format where you manage pointers with a static value.

As Chris mentions below, deleting a null ptr is already handled by delete and free, but I like to include the if statements to remind myself to set the pointer to NULL when its absolutely necessary.

Thanks again Chris :D

Comment: You should almost never use `new` in C++. Manual memory management sucks. Also, deleting a null pointer is a no-op, so it's no less safe, except here, you only delete it if it's null, so memory leaks abound. And C also has `NULL`, and does not have `delete`.

Comment: It's fully made in c. No c++ stuff allowed. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on your line with the comment `//This gives trouble`

With function `doVector` you use `malloc` to create a vector instance somewhere in memory. Then, when dereferencing the result by doing `*doVector(size, data)`, you take the created vector and try to assign it to `vectors[i]`. This copies the memory block of newly created vector into the location `vectors[i]`, but you don't keep the pointer to the result of `doVector`.

Afterwards, you free the memory of `vectors` element by element in the for loop and later you try to free the same space again using `free(vectors)` after the for loop. However, the memory allocated inside `doVector` is never freed, because you don't have the pointers to created vectors.

I would stick to [Ivan Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157639/ivan-ivanov)'s answer for making it correct. I just wanted to point out why it doesn't work.